# how to output textbox value in javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

basically i have a form which inside that form i have a textbox and a submit button, now what i want is to output text box value into console when a user type something, i found this link https://codepen.io/jnnkm/pen/WxWqwX?editors=1111 which works just perfect but when i copied the html and script code and putted it my editor and ran it trough my browser, it doesn't works at all,

here is how i tried it out:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="JquerySock.js"></script>
<script>
function postUsernameToServer() {
console.log('executed function')
  var username = $("#Registeration_Username_box").val();
  console.log(username);
}
$('#Registeration_Username_box').on('input', function() {
  console.log('excuted input');
  postUsernameToServer();
 });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="Registeration_Div" class="Registeration_Div">

  <form class="Registration_Form" id="Registration_Form" action="../postr" method="POST">

    <div id="Registeration_Username_DIV" class="Registeration_Username_DIV">
      <input type="text" id="Registeration_Username_box" class="Registeration_Username_box" placeholder="" name="UserName" maxlength="30" />

</div>
<div class="Registration_Submit_Div">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="SumbitForm_btn" class="SumbitForm_btn" name="Submit_btn" />
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

you can try it yourself too, but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: It looks like you may need to include the jQuery library before you include `JquerySock.js`

Answer (score 0):

okay i found what the problem was, first i had to specify

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

and then input my ajax code, i mean fully it was suppose to be this way

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="JquerySock.js"></script>
<script>
function postUsernameToServer() {

console.log('executed function')
  var username = $("#Registeration_Username_box").val();
  console.log(username);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#Registeration_Username_box').on('input', function() {
  console.log('excuted input');
  postUsernameToServer();
 });
 });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="Registeration_Div" class="Registeration_Div">

  <form class="Registration_Form" id="Registration_Form" action="../postr" method="POST">

    <div id="Registeration_Username_DIV" class="Registeration_Username_DIV">
  <input type="text" id="Registeration_Username_box" class="Registeration_Username_box" placeholder="" name="UserName" maxlength="30" />

    </div>
    <div class="Registration_Submit_Div">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="SumbitForm_btn" class="SumbitForm_btn" name="Submit_btn" />
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

now it works perfect!